# Creating RabbitMQ cluster (by Bitnami) and Kafka cluster (by Bitnami) in Azure and connecting to them from Kubernetes in another v-net

Tags: azure, rabbitmq, virtual-network, kafka, bitnami

I'm trying to create an architecture with: 
1. Kafka cluster (by Bitnami) 
2. Rabbitmq cluster (by Bitnami) 
3. Kubernetes cluster (AKS) that can use both Kafka and RMQ

When I created both clusters (Kafka and RMQ) in Azure, I was asked to create a new resource group for each of the clusters. 
I don't have the IPs of the AKS nodes, so I can't make exceptions in the clusters' virtual networks. When I tried to connect the virtual network of AKS to each cluster using virtual network peering, I was prompted with an error saying that there is an overlap between the addresses, since Bitnami is creating a default subnet of 10.0.0.0/24, and so I can't connect my AKS to the clusters.

I asked Azure support about this issue, and this was their response:

"I just checked that the Bitnami Marketplace images for RabbitMQ Cluster or Kafka Cluster have the VNET address space hard-coded. In such a scenario, I’ll recommend opening up a support ticket with the publisher to see if they can provide a custom template for deployment of their resources for the given scenario."

I already opened a ticket with Bitnami, but still didn't get a response.

Since I'm pretty sure people are using RMQ cluster and Kafka cluster by Bitnami, I wonder what I did wrong in the setup.

What can I do in that case?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. You have to use one vnet for both, aks and rabbit mq with kafka clusters. They could share same subnet or have separate, but under same vnet. To have these bitnami images deployed to your vnet, subnets, you have to save the arm template that gets generated when you pass the configuration wizard when you choose the bitnami image. At the end, before starting the build process, it lets you download templates. Download them, change the templates with your own vnet names, subnets, ip ranges etc, and you can launch everything from template using powershell or via portal.